# What does 'ln-ct' and 'nc-lns' mean in GNU complexity output?

Tags: c, gnu, code-complexity, gnu-complexity

According to [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/complexity/manual/complexity.html#Example-Output), GNU complexity scores look like this:

```
Score | ln-ct | nc-lns| file-name(line): proc-name
    3      13      12   tokenize.c(507): skip_params
    3      15      13   score.c(121): handle_stmt_block
    3      22      17   tokenize.c(64): check_quote
```

Can anyone confirm if `ln-ct` means line count and explain what `nc-lns` means?

Comment: *non-comment-lines*?

Comment: @AlexK. Yup, that's right. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why I didn't just test this, I don't know. Anyway, from messing around with a source file I can confirm:

- `ln-ct` = line count
- `nc-lns` = non-comment lines

Leaving this here in case it's helpful - the manual doesn't describe these terms.